# How reliable is PHP's memory_get_peak_usage?

Tags: php

I have been benchmarking a PHP class I've written. It traverses a MySQL table so you can do things like get the next and previous records on a given query by sending it a unique ID. The class allows you to do this in two ways:

1. Load the entire result set into a PHP variable and get prev/next records by using PHP to loop through the array
2. Perform two MySQL queries and simply send the prev/next record IDs back to PHP

I have set up a test table with about 1,000,000 records; the table size is ~25 MB.

With that in mind, I would expect method 1 to take up a lot more memory than method 2 because the entire result set is being loaded into a PHP variable (though only one of the columns). However, when I call memory_get_peak_usage the memory is always around 0.5 MB. If I pass true as a parameter both return ~0.75 MB. Ironically, method 2 returns a slightly higher memory usage than method 1. I would guess based on the table structure and size method 1 should use about 10 MB more than method 2 yet it doesn't.

How reliable is PHP's memory_get_peak_usage? Is there some clever feature to PHP's memory management that makes it use a lot less than you'd think it needs?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens to the returned value if you retrieve all records in one select statement (if possible), without working with the returned result? That should have some impact unless PHP only counts what actually "enters PHP world"?

Comment: Hi, do you mean if I do $result = $connection->query($query); but then don't do anything with $result? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, something like that. That definitely will use some memory, but I assume you won't see it being used client side (i.e. in PHP).

Comment: Are your queries buffered or unbuffered?  Buffered queries will load your result set into PHP memory regardless of whatever else you do, and they are the default. Try it again with unbuffered queries and let's hear the results.